# WebStorm option to prevent XML/HTML conversion of JavaScript code

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I've recently moved from [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) to [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), and I can't seem to find any option to prevent the IDE from mangling simple JavaScript code upon pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I frequently line my code up (manually) and prefer my IDEs to just get out of my way as much as possible.

As far as I can tell, I've turned off all suggestions, etc., but this is still happening. It does this in various situations, but the most basic example is:

[image: when I press tab following a variable]

I don't have any idea why it would think that I want to convert this line into XML, even less why it wouldn't wrap the value if I wanted to convert this line. Nothing pops up *(no suggestions)* to alert me that something might happen if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

The only extension that I have installed manually is *[EJS](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7296-ejs)* *(and I've confirmed that this is not to blame by disabling it)*. I've disabled all others that look like they could potentially care about JavaScript *(i.e., not disabled version control / [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29), etc.)*.

I'm sure that this is very simple, but it's getting annoying now and I can't find it. How can I do it?

**EDIT**

This is still happening with Emmet disabled. Something else is still going on...

[image: still when I press tab following a variable]

And Emmett is off:

[image: Emmett settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature you are experiencing there is called Emmet and can be disabled in certain contexts such as JSX for example via our settings under **Editor > Emmet > JSX**. If you want to learn more about using Emmet in contexts such as HTML templates (where it hopefully doesn't interfere with your workflow) you can check [our documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html).

[image: Settings page disable Emmet in WebStorm]

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it out! I didn't think to look there because I wasn't using React / JSX at all, just a normal '.js' file. It is worlds better without that "feature" and syntax highlighting seems much faster too.

Comment: @PaulNorman It's probably just less common to use Tab instead of Space or Enter after an identifier which is why Emmet got in your way. Usually it can be very convenient and if you want to give it a try again in applicable contexts (HTML/JSX markup most notably) you can always configure which keybind triggers it.

Comment: Just realised that this is still happening occasionally, so it's more than just Emmet, because that is firmly off. Any ideas would be appreciated.